# Show Outlook content in ASP .NET Core based web UI

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

We are developing a solution to automate several activities related to outlook by utilizing Microsoft Graph API.  The new solution needs to show the email content with inline attachment in a web browser, found a MIME end point (GET /users/{id}/messages/{id}/$value) to get the complete content with inline attachment as base64 but that content is in eml file format. that requires another third part tool to show it in HTML

So would like to know a better solution to show the email content with inline attachment in a web-based solution developed using asp.net core and JavaScript framework like React or Angular.

Comment: Not sure which API you are working with. Can you please more details along with few reproducible snippeet so that it can be investigated accordingly.

Comment: Hi Farid , We  need suggestion and best approach for the above mentioned scenario . basically need to show the mail content with inline attachment in a web based solution using asp.net core and JavaScript frame work

Comment: Well, thanks for your response with clarification. Actually, this is not why eml file was intended for and there is no straight forward best practice. However, If you want to display eml content within your app, you would need to save the file first then you would need a viewer in order to display your content. In addition, you can check for [`any nuget package`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/groupdocs.viewer). You can [`take a look here as a example`](https://products.groupdocs.com/viewer/net/eml/).

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron. Thanks for the quick response. basically, we don't need a complete MIME content with eml file (introducing a new eml viewer is not the option our business expects). Requirement is to show the mail content with inline image in browser. Hope you noticed the web-based version of the outlook can show all inline images seamlessly. So, I’m sure there will be some built in API from graph to do the same but unfortunately I wasn’t able to capture it

Comment: I can confirm that [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) is the right choice for such tasks (to be used from ASP.NET).

Comment: does this eml parser help? https://www.npmjs.com/package/eml-parser

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev. thanks for the response .  do you know which end point we can utilize to get the complete html content with inline image reference that are already processed and part of the html . or stored in a location and referenced

Comment: @AliSheikhpour . tried the parser . it will help to retrieve the html content .. but the inline images are not processed .. so we have to do it again manually . so end of the day it wont bring value